# Setting up custom resolutions with Windows 10 and Intel integrated GPU: Quickly permute all parameters

Tags: resolution

I have a small TFT display without a datasheet. This display is connected to a prototype HDMI interface, so there's no edid information either.

I want to have Windows 10 display an image, but without the correct settings for front porch, back porch, sync width, both horizontal and vertical I can't get it to work.

I tried custom resolutions with the Intel driver, but there are lots of different combinations that I have to try, and setting up a custom resolutions takes time, and it has to be set up manually.

Is there a way to have this trial and error process automated, preferably with Windows, but if there's a solution that requires Linux I will try that as well? After getting the correct values, I will create an edid anyway.

The only things I know for sure: the active area, 480x240, and the size, which is 1.8". It has been taken from a BMW heads-up display, the manufacturer is JDI, and the model is ACX416AKN. From the looks of the PCB it uses 3x6 bit RGB input, no LVDS or RSDS stuff.